# R: How to fill in values in a new column using the values of another column

Tags: r, dataframe, dataset

I have a dataset in R with a column called `event_date`.

The variables look like this:

```
31-Dec-18 
30-Dec-18
28-Dec-18
```

And so on.

I want to create a new column called `date` where I separate out the day of the event. So it looks like:

```
31
30
28
```

I'm pretty new to working with R, so I'm wondering whether a for loop is the way to go, or if there's a more efficient way I don't know about.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's easier to help you if you make your question reproducible including sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions Check out [mre] and [ask]

Answer (score 0):

if the dates are of type character

```
df$date <- sub(".*-.*-(.*)","\\1", df$event_date)
```

otherwise you can look into creating data type objects in R.

Answer (score 0):

If the days are two digit, then `substr` would be faster

```
df$day <- substr(df$event_date, 1, 2)
```

Or convert to `Date` class and extract the `day`

```
df$day <- format(as.Date(df$event_date, "%d-%b-%y"), "%d")
```